# Trying to upload video and change have video player reflect it on the form page

Tags: javascript, video, meteor

I am using meteor and filepicker plus pacakge, I have succesfully gotten image uploading working, however Now I would like to do video, the video uploads and stores it value in a video player for preview however it does not update the player so no video plays yet when I inspect it the correct path is there, if Meteor hot reloads the page without a refresh the video shows up.

Here is the code that changes adds the video path after upload via a session variable. I added the video.load(); thinking that would do the trick, not sure how to get the video to reflect its src change and see the video.

```
'click #uploadVideo':function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    filepicker.pickAndStore(
        {
            mimetypes: ['video/webm'],
            multiple: false
        },{
            access:"public"
        },
        function(InkBlobs){
                                                        // the upload is now complete to filepicker - but the form hasnt persisted the values to our collection yet
        Session.set("videoId", _.last(_.first(InkBlobs).url.split("/")));
        Session.set("videoKey", _.first(InkBlobs).key);




                                                        //  once the session changes are made, the form will now have the new values, including a preview of the image uploaded
    },
    function(FPError){
        log.error(FPError.toString());
    }
);
var video = $('video');
video.load();
```

Comment: When the upload completes, you should store the blob into a collection. Add a [template autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) which will run when the document you just updated gets modified. After modification you should use jquery to append a new `source` value to your `video` element if it doesn't have one already. Finally, call `video.load`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the session value to persistent with the persistent session package and reloading the page worked.

```
     Session.setPersistent("videoId", _.last(_.first(InkBlobs).url.split("/")));
    Session.setPersistent("videoKey", _.first(InkBlobs).key);
    location.reload();
```